# How to display value using EL tags inside text area while value contains HTML tags

Tags: html, jsp, el

I have a JSP display page in which I display all the entities. Currently I am using `${myVariable()}`, but I want to use the value inside the textarea and `myVariable` contains HTML tags inside it. I have tried this code `<td><textarea class="formInputSmall" readonly="readonly" style="width: 300px; height: 100px; ">${myVariable}</textarea></td>` but it displays HTML tags as well.

I would like the text to be displayed as richtext inside textarea without HTML tags.

Comment: That's not possible with simple TextArea. Look at [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com) or [CKeditor](http://www.ckeditor.com).

Comment: i am using Ckeditor to take input but i can't output my text in CKeditor because it does not support readonly mode thanks

Comment: If you want the text to be read-only why use a TextArea then? Just append to a <div> and let the browser render it as html.

Comment: JSTL tags? Where? Do you mean those `${}` things? That's [EL](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info), not [JSTL](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info)!

Comment: Because it is required look and feel for the application later i will put edit button beside it in case user wants to add and if text goes big it can easily be view able inside the text box

Comment: @BalusC sorry about that thanks for mentioning it weather its JSTL or EL i want Value to be displayed inside textArea it does not matter.

Comment: Please to not use Java EE tag on those trivial questions. This is just basic JSP (even more, it boils down to basic HTML; JSP is in the context of this question merely a HTML code generator).